# CSS fill parent height and remaining with

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am facing problems while using flexbox.

Child div fills parent div when I didn't set `align-items: center;`

```css
.outer {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
display: flex;
background-color: red;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I set `align-items: center;` to outer div, `flex: 1 1 auto;` didn't work.

```css
.outer {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
display: flex;
background-color: red;
align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the issue? In the first instance you do not align it so it just grows to fill the space, in the second instance you align it but do not give it any dimensions so it is aligned to the middle but with a width of zero

Comment: i want to set align-items: center; and the inner div to fill parent div

Comment: just give it a width of 100% then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width and height 100%; to inner div

```css
.outer {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
display: flex;
background-color: red;
align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  width : 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its having no content thats why its not taking space, for it to take space, set some height and width on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#main {
    width: 220px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black; 
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center ;
    align-items: center;
}

#main div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;


}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```